# Error in ViewModel After Deleting an Item and Restoring First Item to Editing State in SwiftData

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm, swift-data

I'm working on a SwiftUI app that involves managing a list of items, each with associated sub-items.

My setup includes a CustomsViewModel, MainViewModel, and SubViewModel to handle various aspects of the data.
The models are structured using SwiftData.

**I've encountered an issue where, after deleting an item from the list, attempts to restore the editing state to the first item in the list.**

Specifically, the error occurs when assigning the subName from the item's subModel (**item.subModel.subName**) to subViewModel.subName in the **startEditing method** of **CustomsViewModel**.

Despite the value(**item.subModel.subName**) being present and correctly printed out just before the assignment, the app crashes during this step.

The deletion itself is successful, and the restoration process correctly identifies the first item to return to an editing state.

The error only arises when after deletion, trying to update the SubViewModel with the sub-item details of the newly selected item.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can spot what might be going wrong in this process?
How can I maintain my structure while addressing this error?

Thanks.

** Structural changes are challenging due to the app's design, instant data updates and etc.

Main Model:

```
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

extension SchemaV1 {
    @Model
    public final class MainModel {
        @Attribute(.unique) public let id: UUID
        public var createdAt: Date = Date.now
        public var mainName: String = "Main Name"
        public var isSelected: Bool = false
        @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) public var subModel: SubModel

        init(createdAt: Date,
             mainName: String,
             isSelected: Bool,
             subModel: SubModel) {
            self.id = UUID()
            self.createdAt = createdAt
            self.mainName = mainName
            self.isSelected = isSelected
            self.subModel = subModel
        }
    }
}
```

Sub Model:

```
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

extension SchemaV1 {
    @Model
    public final class SubModel {
        @Attribute(.unique) public let id: UUID = UUID()
        public var subName: String = "Sub Name"

        init(subName: String) {
            self.id = UUID()
            self.subName = subName
        }
    }
}
```

CustomsViewModel:

```
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

class CustomsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var modelContext: ModelContext

    @MainActor
    static let sharedInstance = CustomsViewModel(modelContext: swiftDataTestContainer.mainContext)

    private let mainViewModel = MainViewModel.sharedInstance
    private let subViewModel = SubViewModel.sharedInstance

    @Published var items: [MainModel] = []

    init(modelContext: ModelContext) {
        self.modelContext = modelContext
        self.items = fetchData()
    }

    func fetchData() -> [MainModel] {
        do {
            var fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<MainModel>()
            fetchDescriptor.sortBy = [SortDescriptor<MainModel>(\.createdAt, order: .forward)]
            let items = try modelContext.fetch(fetchDescriptor)
            return items
        } catch {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func startEditing(_ item: MainModel) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {[unowned self] in
            items.forEach { $0.isSelected = false }
            item.isSelected = true
            mainViewModel.mainName = item.mainName
            mainViewModel.isSelected = item.isSelected

            // error only occurs after deletion on here
            subViewModel.subName = item.subModel.subName 
        }
    }

    func addNewItem() {
        let newItem = MainModel(createdAt: Date.now,
                                mainName: mainViewModel.mainName,
                                isSelected: mainViewModel.isSelected,
                                subModel: SubModel(subName: subViewModel.subName))
        insert(newItem)
        startEditing(newItem)
    }

    func insert(_ item: MainModel) {
        modelContext.insert(item)
        save()
    }

    func delete(_ item: MainModel) {
        guard items.count > 1 else {
            print("Cannot delete the last remaining item.")
            return
        }
        modelContext.delete(item)
        save()
        restoreSelectedEditingItem()
    }

    func save() {
        do {
            try modelContext.save()
            items = fetchData()
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func restoreSelectedEditingItem() {
        if let selectedItem = items.first(where: { $0.isSelected }) {
            startEditing(selectedItem)
        }
        else if let firstItem = items.first {
            firstItem.isSelected = true
            startEditing(firstItem)
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewModel:

```
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @MainActor
    static let sharedInstance = MainViewModel(modelContext: swiftDataTestContainer.mainContext)

    var items: [MainModel] = []
    var modelContext: ModelContext

    init(modelContext: ModelContext) {
        self.modelContext = modelContext
        self.items = fetchData()
    }

    @Published var mainName: String = "" {
        didSet {
            updateMainName()
        }
    }

    @Published var isSelected: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            updateIsSelected()
            items = fetchData()
        }
    }

    private func updateMainName() {
        guard let selectedItem = items.first(where: { $0.isSelected }) else { return }
        selectedItem.mainName = mainName
        save()
    }

    private func updateIsSelected() {
        guard let selectedItem = items.first(where: { $0.isSelected }) else { return }
        selectedItem.isSelected = isSelected
        save()
    }

    func fetchData() -> [MainModel] {
        do {
            var fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<MainModel>()
            fetchDescriptor.sortBy = [SortDescriptor<MainModel>(\.createdAt, order: .reverse)]
            let items = try modelContext.fetch(fetchDescriptor)
            return items
        }
        catch {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    private func save() {
        do {
            try modelContext.save()
            items = fetchData()
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

SubViewModel:

```
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

class SubViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @MainActor
    static let sharedInstance = SubViewModel(modelContext: swiftDataTestContainer.mainContext)

    var items: [MainModel] = []
    var modelContext: ModelContext

    init(modelContext: ModelContext) {
        self.modelContext = modelContext
        self.items = fetchData()
    }

    @Published var subName: String = "" {
        didSet {
            updateSubName()
        }
    }

    private func updateSubName() {
        guard let selectedItem = items.first(where: { $0.isSelected }) else { return }
        selectedItem.subModel.subName = subName
    }

    func fetchData() -> [MainModel] {
        do {
            var fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<MainModel>()
            fetchDescriptor.sortBy = [SortDescriptor<MainModel>(\.createdAt, order: .reverse)]
            let items = try modelContext.fetch(fetchDescriptor)
            return items
        }
        catch {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    private func save() {
        do {
            try modelContext.save()
            items = fetchData()
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) public var subModel: SubModel
{
    @storageRestrictions(accesses: _$backingData, initializes: _subModel)
    init(initialValue) {
        _$backingData.setValue(forKey: \.subModel, to: initialValue)
        _subModel = _SwiftDataNoType()
    }
    get {
        _$observationRegistrar.access(self, keyPath: \.subModel) // <<
        return self.getValue(forKey: \.subModel)
    }
    set {
        _$observationRegistrar.withMutation(of: self, keyPath: \.subModel) {
            self.setValue(forKey: \.subModel, to: newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since your code is heavily dependent on actors you should remove all references to GCD such as DispatchQueue. They aren’t compatible, the new Concurrency replaces it.

Comment: In SwiftUI the `View` data struct hierarchy is the view model already so you can just remove all those view model objects.

Comment: error fixed with making SubModel to optional